# What is the Ruby regex for including apostrophes?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm currently doing an exercism.io for Ruby and can't pass the last test. The last test reads :

```
def test_with_apostrophes
  phrase = Phrase.new("First: don't laugh. Then: don't cry.")
  counts = {"first"=>1, "don't"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "then"=>1, "cry"=>1}
  assert_equal counts, phrase.word_count
end
```

Error I am receiving is :

```
1) Failure:
 PhraseTest#test_with_apostrophes [word_count_test.rb:61]:
 --- expected
 +++ actual
 @@ -1 +1 @@
 -{"first"=>1, "don't"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "then"=>1, "cry"=>1}
 +{"first"=>1, "don"=>2, "t"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "then"=>1, "cry"=>1}
```

My current code is :

```
class Phrase
  attr_reader :input

  def initialize(input)
    @input = input
  end

  def word_count
    count = {}
    splitted = input.downcase.scan(/\w+/)
    splitted.each do | word |
    if !count.key?(word)
     count[word] = 1
    else
     count[word] = count[word] + 1
    end
  end
  count
 end
end
```

What is the Regex for including the apostrophe?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a "character class", as described in http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

So, instead of `\w+`, you can use `[\w']+`, which says you want one or more of *either* a word character or an apostrophe.

Comment: Updated the question with your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: This worked : splitted = input.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)

Comment: Right, that's what I suggested, modulo the w capitalization typo. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
splitted = input.downcase.scan(/[\w-']+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for getting your frequency of words,

```
words_freq = Hash.new(0)

"First: don't laugh. Then: don't cry.".split(/\s+/).each { |word| words_freq[word.downcase.delete(':|.')] += 1 }
```

gives `#words_freq = {"first"=>1, "don't"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "then"=>1, "cry"=>1}`

Comment: This won't pass for a couple of reasons. Firstly, the colons are in the matched words. Secondly, the keys in `words_freq` have capital letters in them.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all solutions above but none of them worked for me when testing the Regex against "First: don't laugh. Then: don't cry.".

I've used `splitted = input.downcase.scan(/\w+\'*\w|\w/)` instead.

You can also refactor your `word_acount` method to use `each_with_object` like so:

```rb
["don't","do","don't","try"].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |item, hash|
  hash[item] += 1
end
=> { "don't" => 2, "do" => 1, "try" => 1 }
```